# Alternating messages on chatbot creation

Tags: node.js, instagram, chatbot

I'm doing a chatbot with Node JS for Instagram using this library available on github(https://github.com/Androz2091/insta.js.git). I'm currently testing the feature through the online replit platform, I'm getting the message from the instagram user and sending it through a url to the reply service

I have a difficulty that would be the bot's answer. It must follow a message structure, however, this structure is often toggled.

**I send in the chat:**

-Hi

**The bot responds in the console:**

-Hello!

-How can I help you?

**but in the chat he responds like this:**

-How can I help you?

-Hello!

Below is the code I used to go through the arrays I receive and send the messages

I tried using a switch case to try to solve the problem, but it still remains the same.

```
node-fetch(`instagram?mensage=${message}&user=${message.author.fullName}&session=${client.user}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {


      message.chat.sendMessage(json[i].text || json[i].title);
      console.log(json[i].text || json[i].title)


      for (var key in json[i]) {

      /* switch case
     switch(json[i][key]){
       case json[i].text:
        message.chat.sendMessage(json[i].text);
        break;
       case json[i].title:
        message.chat.sendMessage(json[i].title);
        break;
      }*/

        if (json[i][key].length == 3) {
          for (var j = 0; j < json[i][key].length; j++) {

            message.chat.sendMessage(json[i][key][j].label);
            console.log(json[i][key][j].label);

          }
        }
```

Does anyone know why this happens?
I already thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sendMessage](https://github.com/Androz2091/insta.js/blob/master/src/structures/Chat.js#L210)  returns Promise, but you are using it as a normal function.

You can read about javascript promises here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises.

In your code, it should look something like this

```
...
.then(async json => {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        await message.chat.sendMessage(json[i].text || json[i].title);
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I made this adjustment and it really worked!
the way I was testing the asynchronous functions was totally different. Thank you